# The form data perfectly adds data to DB in localhost but when hosted in Heroku it throws 400 error as bad request. I tried a lot but nothings works

Tags: javascript, reactjs

It works fine when I use localhost. I am also using the correct URl in the frontend. It works for getting data and editing data but donot work when i try to post data using formdata using heroku URL.

Order.controller.js

```
const { cloudinaryUpload } = require('../middleware/cloudinary');
const Order = require('../Model/Order');

const addData= (req, res, next) => {
        let data = JSON.parse(req.body.order);
        data.files = req.files
        console.log(data);
        const OrderData = new Order({})
        let mappedData = mapOrder(OrderData, data);
        mappedData.save((err, saved) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err)
                return next({
                    msg: err,
                    status: 400
                })
            }
            res.json({
                msg: "Submitted successfully"
            })
        })
        // cloudinaryUpload(mappedData.referenceImage1.image)
        //     .then((response) => {
        //         mappedData.referenceImage1.image = response.public_id
        //     })
        //     .catch((error) => {
        //         console.log(err)

        //         return next({
        //             msg: error,
        //             status: 400
        //         })
        //     })

    }

const GetData=(req, res, next) => {
        Order.find({ orderStatus: "processing" }, (err, orders) => {
            if (err) {
                return next({
                    msg: err,
                    status: 404
                })
            }
            res.json({
                orders: orders
            })
        })
    }

const EditData=(req, res, next) => {
        let ID = req.query.id
        Order.find({ OrderId: ID }, (err, order) => {
            if (err) {
                return next({
                    msg: err,
                    status: 404
                })
            }
            order[0].orderStatus = "ReadyToPickUp"
            order[0].save((err, updated) => {
                if (err) {
                    return next({
                        msg: err
                    })
                }
                res.json({
                    order: updated
                })
            })
        })
    }


function mapOrder(OrderData, data) {
    OrderData.orderType = data.OrderType
    OrderData.customer.fullname = data.name;
    OrderData.customer.phone = data.phone;
    OrderData.customer.optionalPhone = data.optionalPhone || "";
    OrderData.customer.address = data.address;
    OrderData.cakeDescription.weight = data.Weight;
    OrderData.cakeDescription.flavor = data.Flavor;
    OrderData.cakeDescription.shape = data.Shape;
    OrderData.cakeDescription.eggless = data.eggless;
    OrderData.cakeDescription.messageoncake = data.messageoncake || "";
    OrderData.orderStatus = "processing";
    if (data.files[0]) {
        OrderData.referenceImage1.image = data.files[0].filename
    }
    if (data.files[1]) {
        OrderData.referenceImage2.image = data.files[1].filename
    }
    OrderData.referenceImage1.note = data.ImageNote1
    OrderData.referenceImage2.note = data.ImageNote2
    OrderData.deliveryDate = data.date;
    OrderData.deliveryTime = data.time;
    OrderData.amount = data.Amount;
    OrderData.advancePaid = data.advance;
    return OrderData;
}

module.exports = {
    addData,GetData,EditData
};
```

Imagehandler.js

```
const multer = require('multer');
const path = require('path');

const storage= multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function(req,file,cb){
        cb(null,path.join(process.cwd(),'/uploads'))
    },
    filename : function(req,file,cb){
        cb(null,Date.now()+'-'+file.originalname)
    }
})

const fileFilter=(req,file,cb)=>{
    let image = file.mimetype // mimetype is type of image/jpeg
    let fileType = image.split('/')
    if(fileType[0] === "image" ){
        cb(null,true)
    }
    else{
        req.fileError = true;
        cb(null,false)
    }
}

var upload = multer({ storage: storage, fileFilter: fileFilter})

module.exports = upload
```

app.route.js

```
const router = require('express').Router();
const upload = require('./middleware/imagehandler');
const {addData,EditData,GetData} = require('./api/order.controller');

router.post('/addorder',upload.array('images',3),addData)
router.put('/editorder',EditData)
router.get('/getorder',GetData)

module.exports = router
```

App.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path')
const cors = require('cors')
const orderRouter = require('./api/order.controller');
const dotenv = require('dotenv').config(); // it checks defalut .env file if present and cofigure it.
require('./db.initialize');

app.use(cors());
app.use('/api',orderRouter);

app.use('/files',express.static(path.join(process.cwd(),'/uploads')))

app.use((req,res,next)=>{
    res.json({
        msg: "Error occured",
        satus: 400
    })
})

// it recieves error from next and we can use the error information
app.use((error,req,res,next)=>{ // error handler
    res.status(error.status || 400)
    res.json({
        msg : error.msg || "Error",
        status: error.status || 400
    })
})

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080,(err,done)=>{
    if(err){
        console.log("Server failed")
    }
    else{
        console.log("Server Started at",process.env.PORT);
        
    }
})
```

db.initialize.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const {DB_NAME} = require('./configs/index.config')

 let DBURL=`mongodb+srv://bibekdb:password@webapp.iqxjb.mongodb.net/${DB_NAME}?retryWrites=true&w=majority`

mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI || DBURL,{
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
})
.then((done)=>{
    console.log("Heroku");
    console.log("DB connected successfully..",process.env.DB_NAME);
})
.catch((error)=>{
    console.log("Db connection failed")
})
```

httpClient.js
I am hitting the correct API using xhr and sending data using formdata. I dont know what i am missing

```
import axios from 'axios';

const base_URL = process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL;

const https = axios.create({
    baseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL,
    timeout: 10000,
    timeoutErrorMessage: "Server timeout",
    responseType: "json",
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': "application/json"
    }
})

const GET =(url)=>{
    return https.get(url)
}

const EDIT =(url,params)=>{
    return https.put(url,null,{
        params
    })
}

const Upload = (method, url, data = {}, files = []) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        const formdata = new FormData()

        const orderData = JSON.stringify(data);
        formdata.append('order',orderData)
        files.forEach((file, index) => {
            formdata.append('images', file, file.name)
        })
        xhr.onreadystatechange=()=> {
            if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
                if (xhr.status === 200) {
                    resolve(xhr.response)
                }
                else {
                    reject(xhr.response)
                }
            }
        }
        xhr.open(method, `${base_URL}${url}`)
        xhr.send(formdata);
    })
}
```

Comment: I'm not seeing any debugging code. Have you determined which line exactly causes the error 400 (you're returning yourself all over the place)?

Comment: httpClient.js- Upload => xhr.send(formdata); Here I am getting bad request 400

Comment: Yes, but where does your server-side code fail?

Comment: It is not hitting my API  in order.controller.js=  .post(upload.array('images', 2), (req, res, next) =>                                                                                                                                When I use localhost I can add data to DB but when I use heroku URl for hitting API to add data browser throws 400 bad request error

Comment: You mean `console.log(data);` in your POST route is never hit?

Comment: yes it is never hit and Heroku logs also don't show the console.log(data).                           * Heroku logs shows=>heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/api/addorder"  service=563ms status=400 bytes=276 protocol=https                                                       But getOrder and EditOrder API works perfectly                                                               *heroku log =>method=GET path="/api/getorder"  connect=0ms service=61ms status=200 bytes=849 protocol=https

Comment: But isn't the route `/api/order`? And if your form tries to submit to `/api/addorder`, how did this work on localhost?

Comment: I edited it just recently and separated file of route and controller and I have edited the question's code as well. I don't what's wrong with the code

Comment: Is `require('./middleware/imagehandler');` properly calling `next()`? And what's inside? You're not showing the imagehandler code.

Comment: I have edited question as you mentioned

Comment: So the current code does work fine on localhost? Do more debugging and find the exact spot where the code breaks.